# how to share the session on multiple servers with hapijs?

Tags: node.js, session, hapi.js

how do I share session across multiple servers? 
I'm using nodejs + hapijs + yar and I want to share the session with many restful servers.
thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to store your sessions in one or more Redis instances. I've done this plenty of times before, albeit with Express.

Comment: Thank you for help!
I managed to solve. 
The problem was in the configuration of a module AngularJS, restangular. 

`RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({
        withCredentials: true
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve. The problem was in the configuration of a module AngularJS, restangular.

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({ withCredentials: true });
```

And Hapi server configuration:

```
cors: {origin :['https://www.xxxx.xxx'],credentials: true } ,
    cache: {
        engine: 'catbox-redis',
        host:'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        port:6379,
        shared: true
    }
```

thank you